# Weird polyline mapbox when drawing on android from pgRouting

Tags: geojson, mapbox, android

I am creating android apps which can show the route that generated from pgRouting, and return geojson file.

I already can draw the polyline on the web with mapbox-gl js with this code:

```
var geojson = {
          "type": "FeatureCollection",
          "features": []
        };

for(var i=0; i<data[0].length - 1; i++)
        {
            $json = JSON.parse(data[0][i]['json']);
            geojson.features.push($json);
        }

map.addLayer({
                        "id": "rute",
                        "type": "line",
                        "source": {
                            "type": "geojson",
                            "data": geojson
                        },
                        "layout": {
                            "line-join": "round",
                            "line-cap": "round"
                        },
                        "paint": {
                            "line-color": "#009688",
                            "line-width": 3
                        }
                    });
```

and the result is good like this:

[image]

But, when i draw the polyline on android with this code:

```
private ArrayList<LatLng> latLngs = new ArrayList<>();
for(int i=0; i<array_geocoordinate.length(); i++)
                            {
                                String[] koordinat = array_geocoordinate.get(i).toString().split(",");
                                LatLng koordinat_baru = new LatLng(Double.valueOf(koordinat[1].split("\\]")[0]), Double.valueOf(koordinat[0].split("\\[")[1]));
                                    Log.d(koordinat[0].split("\\[")[1] + ",", koordinat[1].split("\\]")[0]);
                                    latLngs.add(koordinat_baru);
                            }

map.addPolyline(new PolylineOptions()
                        .addAll(latLngs)
                        .color(Color.parseColor("#3bb2d0"))
                        .width(2));
```

The line of route become like this:

[image]

There're many polylines that draw incorrectly, how to fix that?